# Find two matrices where ${\bf A}{\bf B}= {\bf 0}$ but not even single element is $0$

Tags: matrices

Find two $2 \times 2$ matrices that contain no $0$ elements but obey ${\bf A}{\bf B} = {\bf 0}$.

Comment: Random 2x2 matrices so far

Comment: Random probably won't work. Maybe try to write the entries of $AB$ in terms of the ones of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Tuki: Have you tried doing what I suggested?

Comment: @GuidoA. I can now find multiple correct solutions with this method. and i have some level of understanding to how this works.

Comment: Great. I'd recommed you to look into Ted's approach. You can write the product matrix entries as the dot product of $A$ and $B$'s rows/columns, and then use properties of it to find more examples. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Guido A's hint, let's write a general equation and see what this requires. Let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}x & y \\ z & w\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now compute their product
$$
AB=\begin{pmatrix}ax+bz & ay+bw \\ cx+dz & cy+dw\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In order for this to be zero, we must have
$$
ax+bz = ay+bw=cx+dz=cy+dw = 0.
$$
Try finding a solution to this equation in which all terms are nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Try two rows multiples of one another, and two columns orthogonal to those vectors.